# can not login ubuntu 16.04 cycles loop with slow cursor buggy

Tags: 16.04

After installing updates in the AM of 8/31/16, and rebooting, 1st, I could login to my desktop with top & sidebars gone, and without gear to shutdown/restart.
Then, after trying various recovery options, when I try to login, it accepts my password, then burps back the pw prompt, with a ~ 1 inch blinky piece of my desktop pic on top, and slow buggy cursor.

I am using the Intel HD video built into the I3 cpu, if that helps. HELP!

Answer (score 0):

I have had this happen to me, and this is what I did to fix the issue.
Check the permissions of .Xauthority
 ls -l .Xauthority
-rw------- 1 user user 153 Sep  2 15:50 .Xauthority

If it is showing root root, simply enter this:
sudo rm .Xauthority
touch .Xauthority
sudo chown user:user .Xauthority
sudo reboot

If you are still being bounced of your login screen and back, please try:
ls -l .ICEauthority
-rw------- 1 user user 153 Sep  2 15:50 .ICEauthority
If you are showing root root, then
sudo rm .ICEauthority
touch .ICEauthority
sudo chown user:user .ICEauthority

Comment: Thank you for the above, tried all, it did not work though. I keep on getting booted back to the login screen. Any other recommendations? The slow cursor/flashing inch on top is gone though. I am doing this by accessing the recovery tools and launching networking, then a root shell.

Comment: Would it be helpful if I added the terminal details? Basically, the start point after I put the password in is root@(user)(putername). After that, the sudo & touch rm(s) are accepted without any further system dialogue.

Comment: OK, I did succeed in solving the login loop issue by accessing the tty terminal at the boot screen by using the above sudo rm .Xauthority commands, however I am now on my desktop missing the top/side toolbars. I tried various commands to reset compiz/nautilus/unity that so far have not succeeded. Thanks for any other suggestions anyone can come up with. :)